# Connecting an old MySQL server to the latest Django installation

Tags: python, django

I'm making a Django project that connects to an external MySQL database for a college project. The problem is that the database is outdated, and I keep getting the error message, "MySQL 8.0.11 or later is required (found 5.6.40)."

I cannot update the database server and I would like to keep using the latest version of Django. If I were to create a middleware to convert the response from the database to a format readable to the Django 5.0.1, what would be the topics I would need to learn?

I added the external database to the settings.py along with the main database. I also used connections from django.db to make queries so I would not have to add the entire database to models.py.

Answer (score 0):

What you wish to do is currently not possible,
and making it possible would produce a support nightmare
for the Django authors.
There's a reason they don't support running under
a 2.6 or 3.3 interpreter.
There's a reason they don't try to test against and
support ancient databases which are missing modern
features and have interesting sets of bugs to worry about.
Not even the database vendor was willing to support MySQL 5.6
past its EOL date that
[expired](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Release_history) way back in 2021.

> I cannot update the database server

Right.
That particular database server is not a candidate
for deploying a Django solution.
Its DBA is unwilling to address your needs.

Install a MySQL 8.0.11 or later database, already!
It's easy to do.
Run it on your laptop, run it in a cloud docker container, whatever.
You can even find [pre-made images](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) for doing exactly that.
(Possibly you would prefer to use 8.0 LTS,
since the 8.3 release doesn't come with the
same guarantees of Long Term Support through 2026.)

If necessary, use
[mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/mysqldump.html)
or CSV exports
to copy rows from old database to the new one.

The sign next to the roller coaster
says you must be 80 cm tall to enter.
If you don't meet the requirements,
you don't get to ride the ride.

Comment: The problem is the database server is from a client company we had to find. But thank you! My group and I will just have to ask them if they're willing to update their database.

Comment: You explained you have read access to table rows in the old DB right now. So you don't need to convince folks at that company to do anything immediately. You are in the driver's seat, you can install an 8.3 DB server yourself, transfer table rows yourself, and put together a Django MVP that demonstrates business value. Then folks at the company can decide whether the value proposition is compelling enough to install their own 8.3 server, or not.

Comment: That's actually really smart. Thank you very much!